# Task role not found in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

In AWS, when I try to create a task definition, it shows nothing (I am in EU-Central region).

[image: notfound]

However when I go to IAM I do have roles that have policies needed to pull my images. How can I select one of these existing roles when creating my task def when nothing shows up in the list?

[image: roles list]

By the way this is the error:

[image: error]

Comment: Those `AWSxxx` roles are AWS managed but are only typically assumable by an AWS service (via configured trust relationship).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AWS every role has a `Trusted Entity`. This trusted entity specifies who or what can assume a role, meaning that for example a Lambda Function can not assume a role create for an ECS Task, or a human user can not assume a role create for an EC2 machine.

For an ECS task, you have a to create a role which has the trusted entity of `ecs-task`:

[image]

If you have a task which has the correct trusted entity, it will show up afterwards in the dropdown.

Comment: Now I get `Fargate requires task definition to have execution role ARN to support ECR images`

Comment: If you create a role, you have to have the correct policies attached to it. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html

Comment: worked, thanks... How th are people supposed to just figure this out ffs